# How can I display a new div with text after a user inputs this text and hits submit?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to simulate a chat messaging system using pure JS (no server though, so really just uploading and displaying text) but am having trouble as I'm pretty new to JavaScript. I wrote this code but nothing happens when I click submit. Is my code having a huge error anywhere that I am not catching? If so, how can I fix it?

I am trying to use the javascript function to generate a div under the class container, with parent div chatMsg.

```
<div id="chatMsg" class = "chatMsg" >
    <div class="container">

    //some other HTML here

    </div>

</div>

<div class = "sendText">
    <form name = "sendMsg">
        <textarea name="Message" class="msg" ></textarea>
        <input type="submit" name = "submit" value="Send!" onclick = "addChatMessage()">
    </form>
</div>
```

```
<script>
    function addChatMessage() {
        var chat = document.getElementById('Message'); // finds the container
        var div = document.createElement('div');
            div.id = "newMsg";
            div.className = "container";
            div.innerHTML = chat.value;
        var parDiv = document.getElementById('chatMsg');
        parDiv.appendChild(div);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: A submit button always submits a form to the server. You have to prevent that default action. See [How to prevent buttons from submitting forms](//stackoverflow.com/q/932653)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent buttons from submitting forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932653/how-to-prevent-buttons-from-submitting-forms)

Answer (score 1):

A few things...

1) You need to give the textarea an `id` attribute:

```
<textarea id="Message" name="Message" class="msg" ></textarea>
```

Now, you can use `document.getElementById('Message')` to get it.

2) You should create new elements with unique ids. A counter variable could be used to increase the id by one each time:

```
var counter = 0;
div.id = "newMsg" + counter++;
div.className = "container";
div.innerHTML = chat.value;
```

3) Use an input type of `button` instead of `submit` if you don't want it to post to a server.

```
<input type="button" id="submit" value="Send!" onclick = "addChatMessage()">
```

---

Putting it all together:

```js
var counter = 0;
function addChatMessage() {
    var chat = document.getElementById('Message'); // finds the container
    var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.id = "newMsg" + counter++;
        div.className = "container";
        div.innerHTML = chat.value;
    var submitMsg = document.getElementById('submit');
    var parDiv = document.getElementById('chatMsg');
        parDiv.appendChild(div);
}
```

```html
<div id="chatMsg" class = "chatMsg" >
    <div class="container">
        //some other HTML here
    </div>
</div>

<div class = "sendText">
    <form name = "sendMsg">
        <textarea id="Message" name="Message" class="msg" ></textarea>
        <input type="button" id="submit" value="Send!" onclick = "addChatMessage()">
    </form>
</div>
```